# Django Generic Views, design guide

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I accept that the question is a bit subjective, and that it does not pin point at certain technical doubt/query, but i wanted to know.

I am a newbie in django, after 3-4 months of doing apps in django i am trying to dig-down-deep. 
I am currently reading a book by [James Brennet](http://www.b-list.org/) where he shows how to use generic views, but when i head to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/ i see generic views are depricated.

From the "best design perspective" point of view, how is using generic views rated?

Is it considered a good practice to use generic views?

If yes why is then django depricating it?

If no, what else is recommended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The old generic views are deprecated because they've been replaced with 'Class-based generic views':
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

If you have a lot of view which repeatedly express the same pattern, for example a set of CReate/Update/Delete (CRUD) views for several models... where most of the view code is the same but just some specifics change, eg the model class and final redirect url... this is where generic views make sense.

The goal is to be DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) ...ie write the code in one place and re-use, catch and fix bugs in one place etc.

Comment: @user902620: The benefit to class-based generic views is that they truly are generic. With old-style generic views, they served more as scaffolding does in Rails. You could get something running quick with them, but it wasn't long before you'd have to end up writing your own customized views. With class-based generic views, you can inherit from the basic type of view you need and then go ahead an add all your custom functionality without having to ever rewrite any basic code.